# Wrong Yarn node label mapping with AWS EMR machine types

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, amazon-emr

Does anyone have experience with Yarn node labels on AWS EMR? If so you please share your thoughts. We want to run All the Spark executors on Task(Spot) machine and all the Spark ApplicationMaster/Driver on Core(on-Demand) machine. Previously we were running Spark executors and Spark Driver all on the CORE machine(on-demand).

In order to achieve this, we have created the "TASK" yarn node label as a part of a custom AWS EMR Bootstrap action. And Have mapped the same "TASK" yarn label when any Spot instance is registered with AWS EMR in a separate bootstrap action. As "CORE" is the default yarn node label expression, so we are simply mapping it with an on-demand instance upon registration of the node in the bootstrap action.

We are using `"spark.yarn.executor.nodeLabelExpression": "TASK"` spark conf to launch spark executors on Task nodes.

So.. we are facing the problem of the wrong mapping of the Yarn node label with the appropriate machine i.e For a short duration of time(around 1-2 mins) the "TASK" yarn node label is mapped with on-demand instances and "CORE" yarn node label is mapped with spot instance. So During this short duration of wrong labeling Yarn launches Spark executors on On-demand instances and Spark drivers on Spot instances.

This wrong mapping of labels with corresponding machine type persists till the bootstrap actions are complete and after that, the mapping is automatically resolved to its correct state.

The script we are running as a part of the bootstrap action:

This script is run on all new machines to assign a label to that machine. The script is being run as a background PID as the yarn is only available after all  custom bootstrap actions are completed

```html
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -ex

function waitTillYarnComesUp() {
  IS_YARN_EXIST=$(which yarn | grep -i yarn | wc -l)
  while [ $IS_YARN_EXIST != '1' ]
  do
    echo "Yarn not exist"
    sleep 15
      IS_YARN_EXIST=$(which yarn | grep -i yarn | wc -l)
  done

  echo "Yarn exist.."
}

function waitTillTaskLabelSyncs() {
  LABEL_EXIST=$(yarn cluster --list-node-labels | grep -i TASK | wc -l)
  while [ $LABEL_EXIST -eq 0 ]
  do
    sleep 15
    LABEL_EXIST=$(yarn cluster --list-node-labels | grep -i TASK | wc -l)
  done
}

function getHostInstanceTypeAndApplyLabel() {
  HOST_IP=$(curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-hostname)
  echo "host ip is ${HOST_IP}"
  INSTANCE_TYPE=$(curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-life-cycle)
  echo "instance type is ${INSTANCE_TYPE}"
  PORT_NUMBER=8041
  spot="spot"
  onDemand="on-demand"

  if [ $INSTANCE_TYPE == $spot ];  then
    yarn rmadmin -replaceLabelsOnNode "${HOST_IP}:${PORT_NUMBER}=TASK"
  elif [ $INSTANCE_TYPE == $onDemand ]
  then
    yarn rmadmin -replaceLabelsOnNode "${HOST_IP}:${PORT_NUMBER}=CORE"

  fi
}

waitTillYarnComesUp
# holding for resource manager sync
sleep 100
waitTillTaskLabelSyncs
getHostInstanceTypeAndApplyLabel
exit 0
```

```html
yarn rmadmin -addToClusterNodeLabels "TASK(exclusive=false)"
```

This command is being run on the Master instance to create a new TASK yarn node label at the time of cluster creation.

Does anyone have clue to prevent this wrong mapping of labels?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to propose the next:

1. Create every node with some default label, like `LABEL_PENDING`. You can do it using the EMR classifications;
2. In the bootstrap script, you should identify if the current node is On-Demand or Spot instance;
3. After that, on every node you should update change `LABEL_PENDING` in `/etc/hadoop/conf/yarn-site.xml` to `ON_DEMAND` or `SPOT`;
4. On the master node, you should add 3 labels to YARN: `LABEL_PENDING`, `ON_DEMAND`, and `SPOT`.

Example of EMR Classifications:

```
[
  {
    "classification": "yarn-site",
    "properties": {
      "yarn.node-labels.enabled": "true",
      "yarn.node-labels.am.default-node-label-expression": "ON_DEMAND",
      "yarn.nodemanager.node-labels.provider.configured-node-partition": "LABEL_PENDING"
    },
    "configurations": []
  },
  {
    "classification": "capacity-scheduler",
    "properties": {
      "yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.accessible-node-labels.ON_DEMAND.capacity": "100",
      "yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.accessible-node-labels.SPOT.capacity": "100",
      "yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.default.accessible-node-labels.ON_DEMAND.capacity": "100",
      "yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.default.accessible-node-labels.SPOT.capacity": "100"
    },
    "configurations": []
  },
  {
    "classification": "spark-defaults",
    "properties": {
      "spark.yarn.am.nodeLabelExpression": "ON_DEMAND",
      "spark.yarn.executor.nodeLabelExpression": "SPOT"
    },
    "configurations": []
  }
]
```

Example of the additional part to your bootstrap script

```
yarnNodeLabelConfig="yarn.nodemanager.node-labels.provider.configured-node-partition"
yarnSiteXml="/etc/hadoop/conf/yarn-site.xml"

function waitForYarnConfIsReady() {
  while [[ ! -e $yarnSiteXml ]]; do
    sleep 2
  done

  IS_CONF_PRESENT_IN_FILE=$(grep $yarnNodeLabelConfig $yarnSiteXml | wc -l)
  while [[ $IS_CONF_PRESENT_IN_FILE != "1" ]]
  do
    echo "Yarn conf file doesn't have properties"
    sleep 2
      IS_CONF_PRESENT_IN_FILE=$(grep $yarnNodeLabelConfig $yarnSiteXml | wc -l)
  done
}

function updateLabelInYarnConf() {
  INSTANCE_TYPE=$(curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-life-cycle)
  echo "Instance type is $INSTANCE_TYPE"

  if [[ $INSTANCE_TYPE == "spot" ]];  then
    sudo sed -i 's/>LABEL_PENDING</>SPOT</' $yarnSiteXml
  elif [[ $INSTANCE_TYPE == "on-demand" ]]
  then
    sudo sed -i 's/>LABEL_PENDING</>ON_DEMAND</' $yarnSiteXml
  fi
}

waitForYarnConfIsReady
updateLabelInYarnConf
```